# Adding certain substring prefixes to an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, substring

I'm trying to get this method to add array values to prefixCheck according to a prefix substring, but I keep getting errors when my prefixes are longer than the entries themselves. How do I employ a check for this?

```
/**
 * This method returns a list of all words from the dictionary that start with the given prefix.
 *
 */
public ArrayList<String> wordsStartingWith(String prefix)
{
    ArrayList<String> prefixCheck = new ArrayList<String>();
    int length = prefix.length();
    for(int index = 0; index < words.size(); index++)
    {
        if(length > words.get(index).length())
        {
            if(words.get(index).substring(0, length).equalsIgnoreCase(prefix))
            {
                prefixCheck.add(words.get(index));
            }
        }
    }
    return prefixCheck;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your condition is reversed. Should be `length < words.get(index).length()`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using String.startsWith(String).

```
for(int index = 0; index < words.size(); index++)
{
    if(words.get(index).startsWith(prefix))
            prefixCheck.add(words.get(index));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Rohit!
You were indeed correct!
Changing:

```
if(length > words.get(index).length())
```

to

```
if(length < words.get(index).length())
```

completely solved my String index out of range error.